# javascript selectiong checkboxes to order options dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to  implement a form that has checkboxes to select options and comboboxes to order the selections. I have done this,http://jsbin.com/AmeWahI/1/ 
It works until I click the third checkbox. So, what i want is to when I click a checkbox, I want to order this selection among the current selected ones . For example, if I click all checkboxes, all the comboboxes should display 1,2,3 for ordering. 
if I click first and third checkboxes, both comboboxes should display 1 and 2 since only two elements are clicked.

Comment: display value of all selected checkbox in comboboxes. Does not display value of comboboxes when that checkbox is not checked?

Comment: if a checkbox is not checked, you do not count it for ordering. When a chekbox is clicked, the possible orders should be displayed in comboboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified, see here

http://jsbin.com/AmeWahI/8/

You need to replace your second for loop with this

```
for (var n=0; n<3; n++) {
      var select = document.getElementById("slct"+n);
            var length = select.options.length;
            select.remove(0);
            for (var m = 0; m < length; m++) {
                select.options[m] = null;
            }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, what about if a checkbox is unchecked, they should also preserve the order. For example, I first select all three of checkboxes, then i unchecked the third one, in this case, the order 1 and 2 should be displayed in combobox1 and combobox2.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/UjOYuVA/1 see here, if you wanna preserve selection then create array and save selection values, and in the end restore them if option with those value present in corresponding selection.

Comment: can you please check it out my other related question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690925/automatically-selecting-the-proper-option-in-select-box

Comment: Could you please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690925/update-comboboxs-selected-index-based-on-order-of-the-clicked-checkbox/18706469?noredirect=1#comment27562080_18706469 I am stuck on that and you really helped alot for this question and the new one is related this one?

Comment: I have replied there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of check boxes checked inside the form and based on that you can set the value of select options..

say if i have checked two check boxes 1 and 3..my order of learning is two and you can set the value of select box option to two..

Answer (score 0):

well, when ever any checkbox is checked or unchecked find all the checked checkbox count, clear all the dropdowns item list and add item to the dropdown from 1 to total checked checkbox count only if respective check box is checked.

hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function enableDisable(bEnable, checkboxID) {

            var id = checkboxID.replace("checkbox", "");
            var checkedItems = new Array();
            var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
                if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked === true) {
                    count++;
                    checkedItems.push(inputElems[i].id);
                }

            }

            for (var k = 0; k < checkedItems.length; k++) {

                var idk = checkedItems[k].replace("checkbox", "");
                var select = document.getElementById("slct" + idk);
                var length = select.options.length;

                for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    select.options[i] = null;
                }
            }


            for (var j = 0; j < checkedItems.length; j++) {

                for (var k = 0; k < checkedItems.length; k++) {
                    var id = checkedItems[j].replace("checkbox", "");
                    var combo = document.getElementById("slct" + id);
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    combo.remove(0);
                    option.text = "" + (k + 1);
                    option.value = "" + (k + 1);

                    try {
                        combo.add(option, null); //Standard
                    } catch (error) {
                        combo.add(option); // IE only
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

let me know if any concern